# resuming the azure logic app when a service calls it

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, resume

I have a workflow which gets triggers with a http request. It performs some tasks. Now when I perform my other task B (not via workflow but using the logic functions). 
Now, I want to take some actions based on the data passed from the B based on the flow defined in the workflow. In short, from task B, i want to resume my workflow automatically. 
I did by calling the workflow by

> request.post(

{

> ```
>                     url: setUrl, //here url for the workflow
>                     body: obj,
>                     json: true
>                 }, function (error, response, body) {
>
>                 })
> ```

But this url, is for another workflow A' and not the initially executed workflow for in which i want to continue.
How can i achieve it, using single workflow?

Comment: In your Logic App, you can use an `Http Webhook Action`, You can pass a callback url to your function then your function will finished, use the callback url to call the logic app.

Comment: @Thomas is it same as mentioned in the following [link](https://www.eliostruyf.com/calling-a-custom-webhook-trigger-in-an-azure-logic-app/) ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same :-)

Comment: @18bhavna08 you can call Azure functions directly from LogicApps